# How to tar-gzip a directory and put results inside itself?

Tags: tar, gzip

I would like to backup my entire home directory on Linux. Suppose this directory is the only one I have write permissions to.

How would I tar-gzip this directory and put result inside itself?

Comment: You have write permission for `/tmp`, too.

Answer (score 2):

tar zcf  home-backup.tar.gz --exclude  ./home-backup.tar.gz .

Comment: That would exclude **any** file called `home-backup.tar.gz` not only the one you're creating here. With GNU `tar` (not with `bsdtar`), you can use `--exclude ./home-backup.tar.gz` to avoid it.

Comment: good idea (edit: added `./` to exlcude just the one file)

Answer (score 1):

The already suggested

```
tar zcf home-backup.tar.gz --exclude home-backup.tar.gz .
```

would work, but I don't really like that kind of tars which contain lots of files instead of only one directory. If you want to do the same but as one directory:

```
cd /home
tar -czf yourhome/yourhome.tgz --exclude yourhome.tgz yourhome/
```

In both case you will get an error message:

```
tar: yourhome: file changed as we read it
```

which can be a problem if you want to backup from a script and checking the exit code, and anyway if you ignore this it could hide another problem. You can eliminate this creating an empty tgz before you start the backup:

```
touch yourhome.tgz
```

Comment: You mention another reason for avoiding GNU tar.

Comment: Avoiding a built in well known tool is not always easy. Especially when you don't have root permissions (like in the main question here).

Comment: Even though GNU tar is 5 years younger than star, it had plenty of authors and this is not good. Fixing a reported bug typically takes 20 years and the 1993 announced incremental restore still only works with trivial changes between two incrementals. I am happy if GNU tar unpacks schilytools, so I can compile star ;-) You don't need to be root to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a working modern tar implementation, this will work the way you like out of the box:

```
star -cz . > archive.tar.gz
```

will print the warning:

```
star: 'archive.tar.gz' is the archive. Not dumped.
```

Comment: That also seems to work in libarchive bsdtar, but not GNU tar. `tar zcf archive.tar.gz .` works with my  version of GNU `tar`, but causes the _directory modified_ warning mentioned by @redseven.

Comment: libarchive is quiet but if you take a closer look, it is better than GNU tar.